# How compatible are mammal wombs?

Tags: embryology, mammals

I had read about science working towards the creation of artificial wombs however I wonder how compatible are mammal wombs and connected systems to develop fetuses. What species are so compatible that they would be able to surrogate the embryos and fetuses of another species?

Comment: it is not just the womb.. immune reactions can also cause incompatibility.. even in case of same species... see [erythroblastosis foetalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolytic_disease_of_the_newborn)

Comment: @WYSIWYG thanks i edited and added connected systems to include immune resactions

Answer (score 1):

In short: Not completely, but more than you would expect.

The project to clone a mammoth considered using an adult female elephant as a surrogate mother, so in theory closely related species can do this.